# sql server table restriction on two fields

Tags: sql-server-2008, constraints

I have a table with multiple columns with data periodically inserted. I would like to focus on two fields where if one value is entered in Column A, nothing should be allowed to be entered in column B. Hope this makes sense; I will illustrate below:

```
TABLE TEST
COLUMN a
COLUMN b
COLUMN c 
DATEADDED

INSERT INTO TEST(COLUMN A, COLUMN B)
VALUE('HELLO','HELLO')
```

This should not be allowed to occur but rather a null value should be in either one. Basically a constraint to restrict one value being in either column for a given record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the Check Contraint at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp

In your case you can do do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
    a VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    b VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    c VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    DATEADDED DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    CONSTRAINT chk_AtLeastOneNull CHECK (A IS NULL OR B IS NULL)
)
```

and in the insert if you do

```
insert into Persons(a,b,c) values ('a', 'b', null)
```

you'll get the error

```
Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "chk_AtLeastOneNull". The conflict occurred in database "databasename", table "dbo.Persons".
The statement has been terminated.
```

You can combine other expressions in the check, for instance:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_AtLeastOneNull CHECK (A IS NULL OR (A IS NOT NULL AND B IS NULL))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend that you look at a [Check Constraint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> CHECK constraints enforce domain integrity by limiting the values that
>   are accepted by one or more columns. You can create a CHECK constraint
>   with any logical (Boolean) expression that returns TRUE or FALSE based
>   on the logical operators.
>
> You can apply multiple CHECK constraints to a single column. You can also apply a single >CHECK constraint to multiple columns by creating it at the table level.

Also have a look at [SQL CHECK Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp)

> The CHECK constraint is used to limit the value range that can be
>   placed in a column.
>
> If you define a CHECK constraint on a single column it allows only
>   certain values for this column.
>
> If you define a CHECK constraint on a table it can limit the values in
>   certain columns based on values in other columns in the row.